# Axios delete returning 500 error React json

Tags: reactjs, json, axios

So I have this project where I get products from a json server with axios and useQuery.

But when I try to delete a product using it's ID, I get an internal server error. Which is weird to me because post, put and get all work.

[image: The response in console]

Here is my code:

My delete function in my component:

```
const handleDelete =  () => {
    deleteMutation(product.id)’
};
```

My delete mutation:

```
const {
    mutate:  deleteMutation,
    isLoading: isDeletingProduct,
    isError: isErrorDeletingProduct,
} = useMutation(
    (pid:string) => deleteProduct(pid!),
    {
        onSuccess: () => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries(["products"])
        },
    }
);
```

My delete axios request:

```
export const deleteProduct = async (id: string) => {
    return await axios.delete(`/products/${id}`)
}
```

I figured maybe this would happen because I get that product in the same component as where I delete the product.

Anybody an idea on how to fix this?
If you need more code or info on the structure of the project, feel free to ask me.

I tried preventing default and navigating to a page where I don't try to get the product, but I get the same error and the product doesn't get deleted.

Comment: this is when you contact your backend devs

Comment: What do you mean by that @Taki ? And do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @TobyVertommen He means it is an issue with the API. As you can see the server responds with a 500 error and a message about cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString') So there is an error on that Delete route not caused by axios

Comment: Oh I see, so anything I can do to figure out what's causing the problem?